# WMS - get point data in computer readable form (other than map tile)

Tags: wms

is it possible to get a data from some map services on questions like

- **is there a water on [X,Y]** (i.e. blue colour on map)
- is there a dessert on [X,Y] (i.e. yellow colour on map)
- similarly for any available layer

In language of computers, to know, **where on some location (point,radius) is some layer present** and more ideally, what are its properties (river=1,lake=0,waterfall=0,...)

I get get these data visually just by looking on some map tile presented on screen, but this is hard for computer calculations. I have read WMS reference http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo but I am not any more clever from that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you really interested in sampling the data from tiles, or are you looking for a land cover dataset?

Comment: @Simbamangu dataset seems as a natural choice, but else to do when the WMS service is the only way to the open data.

Comment: Data from online map services is not *open*, necessarily, even though they allow you to *look* at it for free! There are many land cover datasets available online - one list is [here](http://landcover.usgs.gov/landcoverdata.php).

Comment: your tip is good for US researches, i am outside... by law of my country, the outputs of government agencies (maps) are mostly free, but the agencies often publish the data in some crazy way, i.e. in PDF scans. the ongoing courts are forcing them to do it in more open way, but whole process is very slow. quicker approach - to use what we have - to use WMS. so to the initial question...

Comment: Did you look at the link I sent? It is a *global* list of land cover datasets, continent by continent - perhaps something useful there? To answer your original question (which is effectively about classification of online raster images), could you indicate more about what your **source** data look like, perhaps provide a link or example?

Comment: source data image example: http://i.imgur.com/iklEhtp.png which represents type of woods (oak, spruce, ...) in the area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're after - you could classify online raster sources using unsupervised classification.

1. Download raster, and georeference if necessary;
2. Run classification with appropriate number of classes;
3. Determine your values of interest in the resulting raster, and code them as needed.

For example, you could download a world layer from metacarta, pasting the following code directly into the Raster|Conversion|Translate dialogue in QGIS (having downloaded the [.xml file](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms_metacarta_wmsc.xml) to the correct directory):

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -outsize 1000 500 /TEMP/frmt_wms_metacarta_wmsc.xml /TEMP/metacarta_wmsc.png
```

[image]

Find and add the layer to QGIS:

[image]

Open Processing|Toolbox and open "Unsupervised KMeans image classification". For this example, I wanted two classes (water / land) and set the convergence threshold to 95%:

[image]

This gives a raster image with the values 0 (land) and 1 (water):

[image]

Comment: as of "2) run classification" in demo, you distinguished "water/land" but there is not clear how the software knows if water is blue and land dark in raster image.

Comment: Are GDAL+QGIS a tools for the solution, or there might be something more command-line automated? (btw. you have been so helpful! i really appreciate the answer)

Comment: Try it out on your raster - experimentation is key. You will have to determine what values the various colours correspond to in your result. There are other methods to pre-determine the classification based on colour, this is just a relatively easy automated system. There are certainly command-line methods, read up on GRASS solutions.